# How can I draw commutative diagrams in LaTeX?

Tags: diagrams, tikz-cd

I would like to learn to make commutative rectangles using Tikz. How can I do that? I have tried

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{\varphi} \arrow[swap]{dd}{g\circ f} & B \arrow{d}{g} \\
& C
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```

but it draws only a triangle.

Comment: Did you look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115783/commutative-diagrams?

Comment: Either `tikz-cd` or the `psmatrix` environment from `pst-node` (one of the many `pstricks` modules).

Comment: Hi and welcome, you could also check out  [Creating triangle commutative diagram with tikz-cd](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/191462) or [Commutative Diagrams](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115783) or [Commutative Diagrams and TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45741) or [How to draw a single commutative diagram with double-ended arrow?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/210692)

Comment: Your `{dd}` should be `{dr}` for “down and right”.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what you exactly wanted to draw, so I reproduce one of the diagrams from your link, showing how to do it with `pst-node` and with `tikz-cd`. One  of the main differences is that in `pstricks` you first describe the nodes, then the arrows, while with `tikz-cd`, nodes and arrows are described simultaneously.

I load `auto-pst-pdf`, as pdflatex doesn't support postscript instructions. You have to set the `--enable-write18` compiler switch (MiKTeX) or `-shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX). Alternatively, you can compile with `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\uspackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 

\begin{document}
%
 \[ \psset{arrows=->, arrowinset=0.25, linewidth=0.6pt, nodesep=3pt, labelsep=2pt, rowsep=0.7cm, colsep = 1.1cm, shortput =tablr}
 \everypsbox{\scriptstyle}
 \begin{psmatrix}
 A & B\\%
 A_f & B_g
 %%%
 \ncline{1,1}{1,2}^{\varphi} \ncline{1,1}{2,1} <{\varrho_f }
 \ncline{1,2}{2,2} > {\varrho_g}
 \ncline{2,1}{2,2}^{\varphi_f}
 \end{psmatrix}
 \]

\[ \begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{r}{\varphi} \arrow[swap]{d}{\varrho_f} & B \arrow{d}{\varrho_g} \\%
A_f \arrow{r}{\varphi_f}& B_g
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This code does not work for me. It does not produce any of the labels ϱ_f and ϱ_g under xelatex and under pdflatex or lualatex it will not run at all.

Comment: There have been changes in `pstricks` since then. Try removing the `[pdf]` option and load `auto-pst-pdf` (*after* pstricks).

Comment: Nope! It will not run under any of the modern tex engines.

Comment: Did you try `xelatex`?

Comment: @PauloNey: I'm sorry, there was a problem with my editor at the time, which I hadn't noticed: the TeX code for Greek letters had been replaced with real Greek letters (in the code). I've just fixed it. Could you try the updated code?

Comment: Of course I did. xelatex on TeXLive 2018 process it, but does not produce the labels as I have noted on my first comment.

Comment: Please see my previous comment.

Comment: Not it works. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 8):

Purely with Plain TeX math mode:

```
\catcode`\@=11
\newdimen\cdsep
\cdsep=3em

\def\cdstrut{\vrule height .6\cdsep width 0pt depth .4\cdsep}
\def\@cdstrut{{\advance\cdsep by 2em\cdstrut}}

\def\arrow#1#2{
  \ifx d#1
    \llap{$\scriptstyle#2$}\left\downarrow\cdstrut\right.\@cdstrut\fi
  \ifx u#1
    \llap{$\scriptstyle#2$}\left\uparrow\cdstrut\right.\@cdstrut\fi
  \ifx r#1
    \mathop{\hbox to \cdsep{\rightarrowfill}}\limits^{#2}\fi
  \ifx l#1
    \mathop{\hbox to \cdsep{\leftarrowfill}}\limits^{#2}\fi
}
\catcode`\@=12

\cdsep=3em
$$
\matrix{
  A                    & \arrow{r}{\varphi}   & B                    \cr
  \arrow{d}{\varrho_f} &                      & \arrow{d}{\varrho_g} \cr
  A_f                  & \arrow{r}{\varphi_f} & B_g                  \cr
}
$$

\bye
```

> [image]

Answer (score 7):

OK. I learned to make commutative rectangles.

```
\[\begin{tikzcd}
A_f \arrow{r}{\varphi_f} \arrow[swap]{d}{\varrho_x^f} & B_g \arrow{d}{\varrho_x^g} \\
A_x \arrow{r}{\varphi_y} & B_y
\end{tikzcd}
\]
```