# How do I draw the following two diagrams of Van Kampen Theorem using latex codes?

Tags: diagrams

Could help me to do these? I am trying to draw these two diagrams myself, but I could not finish it. Therefore, I am requesting you guys to be kind enough to help me in this case and as I know it will help me a lot.

Here are the two diagrams: [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Try with use of the `tikz-cd` package.

Comment: It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried as this would at least give us some code to start from.. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: I still could not do it myself, but anyway thanks.

Comment: Literally, I have followed this commutative diagram: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218274/how-can-i-draw-commutative-diagrams-in-latex and I could not change it to as what I want above.

Comment: @DavidJames  have a look   text data will have to be punched in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you be able to punch in the data

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[commutative diagrams/every diagram]
\node (P0) at (180:2cm) {A};
\node (P1) at (90:2.3cm) {B} ;
\node (P2) at (-90:2cm) {C};
\node (P3) at (0:2cm) {D};
\path[commutative diagrams/.cd, every arrow, every label]
(P0) edge node[] {A1} (P1)
(P0) edge node[swap] {B1} (P2)
(P2) edge node [swap]{C1} (P3)
(P1) edge node {D1} (P3)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is done. Thank you in advance and this is very much help. Take care and best of luck.

Answer (score 6):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
    & A \ar[dr,"k_*"]   &               \\
\pi_1(U\cap V,p) \ar[ur,"i_*"] \ar[dr,"j_*" ']  
    &                   & \pi_1(X,p).   \\
    & E \ar[ur,"l_*" '] &
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
    \begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small]
    & A \ar[d, hook]\ar[dr,"k_*"]
        &       \\
\pi_1(U\cap V,p) \ar[ur,"i_*"] \ar[dr,"j_*" ']
    & \pi_1(U,p)*\pi_1(V,p) \ar[r,"\phi"]
        & \pi_1(X,p).     \\
    & E \ar[u, hook']\ar[ur,"l_*" ']
        &
    \end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now only need to replace A and E with your math expressions.

Comment: @DavidJames, you are welcome. Now I added firs image too, so now you have starting point for both images  Since answer now solve your question, you can accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)

Comment: Your codes worked with Overleaf but did not work with TexStudio and Kile since I am using them. Can you point out the solution for this point?

Comment: @DavidJames , why you ask me? You accept different answer, so I assume that it solve all your problems .... BTW, I use MIkTeX and WinEdt as editor.

Comment: Yes sure, thank you a lot.

Comment: @DavidJames, my proposed solution is independent from used LaTeX distributions. Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with specific of Kile nor with TeXstudio editors. What error you receive if you copy my MWE to your editor and then compile it?

Comment: The error are: Undefined control sequence \end{tikzcd} ,and Missing \endcsname inserted \end{tikzcd}. Check it if you have time and anyway, I think your help is enough for me so let me try it myself more.