# Increase distance between a formula and the arrow and to change the tip/arc of the hook arrow

Tags: packages, diagrams, xy-pic, commutative-diagrams, xymatrix

My question is the following: for exercise I was drawing the 2nd figure of this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557883/how-do-i-draw-the-following-two-diagrams-of-van-kampen-theorem-using-latex-codes) using `xy` package and I have found some difficulties that I have marked with the red rectangles:

[image]

1. How can I increase the distance between `$\pi_1(U,p)$` and the arc of the hook-arrow that it is different by `xy` package?
2. How can I obtain the same arc of the hook-arrow?
3. How can I obtain the same tip of the image? If I use `cmtip` option I will obtain the tip of `tikz-cd`.

I attach my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=4pc@C=2pc{
& A \ar[dr] \ar@{^{(}->}[d]&\\
\pi_1(U\cap V,p)\ar[ur] \ar[dr] &  \pi_1(U,p)*\pi_1(V,p) \ar[r] & \pi_1(X,p).\\
& \pi_1(V,p) \ar[ur] \ar@{_{(}->}[u]&
}
\end{document}
```

[image: w]

Comment: Hvis is one of the reasons why I nowadays recommend tikz-CD where this is not an issue

Comment: @daleif With all the sincerity I also like old packages like `xy`.

Comment: The hook arrow in xy has been suboptimal since always. Tikz-CD just looks better by default

Comment: @daleif Seeing the picture the hook arrrow it is different of tikz-cd...for the hook arrow it is true. +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Major edit: tikz-cd

I agree with the commenter, that [`tikz-cd`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd) is more capable a package than `xymatrix`. If one were to attempt the same thing using `tikz-cd`, this would be the code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{
    ,row sep=normal
    ,column sep=normal,
    ,/tikz/baseline=0pt
    ,arrow style=tikz
    ,diagrams={>=stealth}
    % ,diagrams={>=stealth'}
    % ,arrows={-Latex}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
                                                            &  & A \arrow[rrdd, "k_*"] \arrow[dd, hook]             &  &               \\
                                                            &  &                                                    &  &               \\
{\pi_1(U\cap V,p)} \arrow[rruu, "i_*"] \arrow[rrdd, "j_*"'] &  & {\pi_1(U,p)*\pi_1(V,p)} \arrow[rr]                 &  & {\pi_1(X,p).} \\
                                                            &  &                                                    &  &               \\
                                                            &  & {\pi_1(V,p)} \arrow[uu, hook'] \arrow[rruu, "l_*"'] &  &              
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

And this the output:

[image: tikz-cd diagram]

## Arrow tips

You can change the arrow tips by exchanging `,diagrams={>=stealth}` with `,diagrams={>=stealth'}` or `,arrows={-Latex}` to just name a few possibilities. Try it out and play with it, it's really fun.

## xymatrix

You have to set the entry default margin `@M=dimen` as specified on page 10 of the manual: https://ctan.org/pkg/xymatrix

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix@M=.75pc@C=2pc{
& A \ar[dr] \ar@{^{(}->}[d] & \\
\pi_1(U\cap V,p)\ar[ur] \ar[dr] &  \pi_1(U,p)*\pi_1(V,p) \ar[r] & \pi_1(X,p).\\
& \pi_1(V,p) \ar[ur] \ar@{_{(}->}[u]&
}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image: @M=dimen]

You could also change the entry height `@H=dimen` *set entry default height*:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\xymatrix@H=1.5pc@C=2pc{
& A \ar[dr] \ar@{^{(}->}[d] & \\
\pi_1(U\cap V,p)\ar[ur] \ar[dr] &  \pi_1(U,p)*\pi_1(V,p) \ar[r] & \pi_1(X,p).\\
& \pi_1(V,p) \ar[ur] \ar@{_{(}->}[u]&
}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

[image: Entry height]

Comment: You were great for my first problem. I've read the manual so many times but I don't understand some parameters. For example, I couldn't find anything to change the vector tips and to better bend the tail of the two vectors. Many of my problems come from not understanding English very well.

Comment: @Sebastiano, have a look at the edit, maybe this brings you closer to the result you desire.

Comment: ☹️ I didn't want to use `tikz-cd` because I wanted to take an old package that I like so much `xy` and see if there are any strategies to get the result of the image.

Comment: I understand you completely. I'm not sure, what you wish can be done with xymatrix. Don't you agree that the tikz-cd solution looks a lot better?

Comment: Of course I totally agree with you and dailef.

Comment: Just wondering as I've never seen them before, what does `=normal` mean?

Comment: @daleif, have a look at page 6 (bottom half): https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd